# SQL Server : return only the first instance of a field value

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio, writing in a query window.

We know we can get all manner of datasets returned using SQL queries, but they are always returned as entire rows.

Is it possible to return only the first value of a field, along with the rest of the fields in the row?

Here is what I get returned in a very simple query, and what I would like to get returned. The desired output is destined to go on a Firefly webpage.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Things like this are really better dealt with in the presentation layer - i.e. where you fetch and handle the query result. SQL is not really suitable for making data pretty to human eyes.

Comment: No and you should not want that either because it adds 0 value (the opposite in fact). This is something the application should handle in the presentation layer.

Comment: Thanks Alex - I understand. If it was SSRS then it would be fine - but the Firefly app can only present SQL output in grid format, so that's why I wanted the format.

Comment: Thanks Igor, that's a good point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (ID INT, Name NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @Tbl        
VALUES  
(300, 'joe'),
(300, 'Fred'),
(300, 'Alan'),
(301, 'Margaret'),
(301, 'Bill'),
(301, 'John')

SELECT
    IIF(ID = LAG(ID) OVER (ORDER BY ID), '', CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(50))) AS NID,
    Name
FROM
    @Tbl
ORDER BY ID
```

Result:

```
NID Name
300 joe
    Fred
    Alan
301 Margaret
    Bill
    John
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a blank space for repeated `ID` then you need to cast `ID` as string.You can try using [**LAG**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh231256.aspx)

```
select case when Id=lag(ID) over(order by ID) then '' else cast(Id as varchar(max)) end as ID,Name from Your_Table
```

Example:

```
create table #Tab1(Id int,Name nvarchar(max))

insert into #Tab1(Id,Name) Values
(301,'A'),
(301,'B'),
(301,'C'),
(302,'A'),
(302,'B'),
(303,'B'),
(304,'B')


select case when Id=lag(Id) over(order by id) then '' else cast(Id as varchar) end as ID,Name from #Tab1
```

Comment: Thanks, A_Name_Does_Not_Matter.

Its not working right now, but that's because of something I've done. I'll update this later.